# locate Error in django templates with multi inheritance

Tags: django, templates

The issue occurs when I'm rendering a template from a view, the template itself includes other templates, that also need other templates, and so forth when an error happened at some level. The console shows ONLY that there is an error when rendering the main template from the view, and it takes a lot of time to know exactly which template in the chain has the error, not like if the error happend in the .py file where it gives the exact file that has it.

My current approach to helping me debug is to use a function that is called from each file when is loaded, so at least I minimize the scope, are there better ways to do the job?

Comment: What IDE are you using? PyCharm allows you to debug Django templates in it's debugger.

Comment: i'm using VS code, Does it tell you for example in which template the error has occurred, 'cause I think that has nothing to do with the IDE

Comment: The error has nothing to do with IDE, but the debugger in IDE can help you find the error. You can add breakpoints in your templates and see where the error is. 

VSCode allows you to debug Django code, but I'm not sure about templates, because it's a bit different. But maybe there are some third party plugins for VScode foe debugging Django templates. Google for them. 

There is a free version of PyCharm, but I don't know if the free version allows you to debug templates.